# Faking onwindowunload with Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, turbolinks

Is there a way to *fake* an `onwindowunload` event with Turbolinks?

Essentially, I am looking for a way to cancel a `page:fetch` event, but couldn't figure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now a mechanism in TurboLinks to cancel a page change.

Here's a lib I made that abstracts the fact that your user may or may not be using TurboLinks : https://gist.github.com/jbourassa/6529382

This code also allows you to simply have multiple handlers for unloading.

And I use it like that:

```
Unloader.register(function() {
    return "Please don't go!!";
});
```

This will automatically be removed on the next successful page change.